# How to remove the brackets from this text

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

So I have been given the task by my tutor to make a small function that returns a description of your zodiac sign but I"m having problems with the final output of the sign description, the output is still in brackets and I don't know how to get them out.

```
(defparameter *month-signs* '((January Capricorn Aquarius 19 nil)
                   (February Aquarius Pisces 18 nil)
                    ....)))

(defparameter *sign-traits* '((Capricorn (You are a goat be happy!))
                              ....)))

(defun cookie (month-signs sign-traits)
  (format t "Please input your month of birth followed by return, and then your day of birth.
e.g january <ret> 22 <ret> Thank You. ~%")
  (let* ((month (read t));reads in month of birth
         (day (read t));reads in day of birth
         (month-assoc (assoc month month-signs)))
    (cond
      ((>=(cadddr month-assoc)day);checks if your sign is the first part of the month
       (format t "You are ~D~%" (cadr month-assoc));if it is, prints your sign and signs description
       (format t "Your sign description is: ~D~%" (cadr(assoc(cadr month-assoc) sign-traits))))
      ((< (cadddr month-assoc)22);same as above but for the other sign
       (format t "You are ~D~%" (caddr month-assoc))
       (format t "Your sign description is: ~D~%" (cadr(assoc(caddr month-assoc) sign-traits)))))))
```

It all works dandy except this bit "(cadr(assoc(caddr month-assoc) sign-traits)" which returns what I want but in brackets and all caps.

```
CL-USER> (cookie *month-signs* *sign-traits*)
Please input your month of birth followed by return, and then your day of birth.
e.g january <ret> 22 <ret> Thank You. 
january
12
You are CAPRICORN
Your sign description is: (YOU ARE A GOAT BE HAPPY)
```

I'm really struggling to work out what I need to get rid of the `(YOU ARE A GOAT BE HAPPY)` on the last bit, I'd like it to just print "Your sign description is: You are a goat be happy." it's probably something obvious that I've missed :\ 
One more thing the .... are just for your sake as the variable is large and would take up a large amount of page space, I slimmed it down as they are all laid out the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the list `'(January Capricorn Aquarius 19 nil)`, the first three elements are **symbols**, which are printed out by the REPL in UPPERCASE. Symbols are different from strings. When you quote a list like this, the literals are treated as symbols, not strings.

Similarly, `'(You are a goat be happy!)` is a list of six symbols. It gets printed out as a list (enclosed in parentheses) of uppercase symbols.

If you replace the symbols and lists with strings:

```
(defparameter *month-signs* '((January "Capricorn" "Aquarius" 19 nil)...

(defparameter *sign-traits* '((Capricorn "You are a goat be happy!")...
```

you should get the output you want.

`read` takes the input as a symbol, so you want to leave the association key (January) as a symbol.

Comment: Thank you! I'm really not surprised it was something so obvious.

Answer (score 4):

**Printing a list with symbols**

Common Lisp can print symbols in many ways. The function `WRITE` gives a basic interface to the printer. We don't want to print string quotes and we want to control how a word gets capitalized.

```
(defun write-sentence (sentence
                       &aux                       ; local variable bindings
                       (*print-escape* nil)       ; no escaping
                       (*print-readably* nil))    ; we don't print for the reader
  (write (first sentence) :case :capitalize)   
  (dolist (word (rest sentence))
    (write " ")
    (write word :case :downcase))
  (write ".")
  (values))                           ; return no values

CL-USER 94 > (write-sentence '(YOU ARE A GOAT BE HAPPY))
You are a goat be happy.
```

**PRINC**

The standard function to print in a human readable form is `PRINC`. It does not provide options, other than to optionally specify the output stream. Those need to be bound in the printer control variables. Here we need to tell `PRINC` which *case* to use:

```
(defun write-sentence (sentence)
  (let ((*print-case* :capitalize))
    (princ (first sentence)))
  (dolist (word (rest sentence))
    (princ " ")
    (let ((*print-case* :downcase))
      (princ word)))
  (princ ".")
  (values))
```

**Format**

Similar functionality can be written in a more compact way using the function `FORMAT`, which includes features to iterate over lists. This example is left as an exercise to decipher:

```
CL-USER 115 > (format t
                      "~{~@(~A~)~@{ ~(~A~)~}~}."
                      '(YOU ARE A GOAT BE HAPPY))
You are a goat be happy.
```

**Case in symbols**

It's also possible to specify symbols with case. They need to be escaped in the source code:

```
|This is a single symbol in Common Lisp!|
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer, a lot of that is over my head as this function I have just made was my first experiment with format. Format is covered in Gentle Guide to Common Lisp, so I'll cross it when I get to it. I went and installed Emacs, SBCL, QL, and Slime so I hope my formatting is a lot better :P